# Why is my pose different in the render vs viewport?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mixamo

Exported a character from RuneScape, used mixamo to rig and export, posed the character and created a key frame by selecting all bones and inserting a keyframe. But when I render my character gets eviscerated. [image]

Comment: I set the origin to geometry with the depth of field option in my camera and that broke the rig. apologies for wasting anyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

I set the origin to geometry with the depth of field option in my camera and that broke the rig. apologies for wasting anyone's time.